# asynchronous wait failed Swift 4 Alamofire

Tags: swift, xcode, asynchronous, alamofire

I've got this block of code in my tests. The code executes with the error "asynchronous wait failed: exceeded timeout......". I would have thought the .fulfill() would kick in but it doesn't... Any ideas on how to get this to run without out the error kicking in?

```
func test_checkUpLoadFileIsThere_returnsString(){
    let expec = expectation(description: "photo viewer")
    let pvc = PhotoTakerViewController()
    let isImageThere = pvc.checkFileExsists("166220.jpg")
    waitForExpectations(timeout: 4, handler: {response in
        expec.fulfill()
        print("Expectation block")
    })

    XCTAssertEqual(isImageThere,"Found File : 166220.jpg","image should be there")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply Leo, but no luck. Same result. Spent the last two days trying to work out how to make this test pass.... Any other ideas on what it could be?

Answer (score 0):

You have to `fulfill()` the expectation before `waitForExpectations`. Right now you have your fulfillment in the wait's failure block, which isn't going to work at all. In fact, this code doesn't look asynchronous, so you don't need an expectation at all. If it is asynchronous, you need to expose a completion handler in which to fulfill the expectation.

Comment: The asynchronous code is called in this line:
let isImageThere = pvc.checkFileExsists("166220.jpg")
I want to test the result it brings back..